# How to get post title by contact form 7

Tags: php, wordpress, contact-form, contact-form-7

I'm using contact form 7 in a website for get `REQUEST QUOTE` of each product.

[Link to example](http://rocketuk.cgtmarketing.com/led-light-components/)

When visitor submit the `REQUEST QUOTE` form then I get a mail with desalts and want to get each single post title in that mail. I used `[_post_title]` code for get single post title and I got title. But I got only one post title from top of the page.

How I can get every single post title in the mail ?

Comment: I also had a similar requirement. What I did is, used jquery to write hidden input field to the form at runtime and set the value of post title got from get_the_title(); Think you got a hint on how you do it

Comment: Can you give me code reference. Please

Answer (score 32):

Here you are,

- `[_remote_ip]`   This tag will be replaced by the sender’s client IP
  address.
- `[_user_agent]`  This tag will be replaced by the sender’s
  user agent information.
- `[_url]` This tag will be replaced by the URL
  of the contact form.
- `[_date]`    This tag will be replaced by the date
  of the submission.
- `[_time]`    This tag will be replaced by the time of
  the submission.
- `[_post_id]` This tag will be replaced by the ID of
  the post which contains the contact form.
- `[_post_name]`   This tag
  will be replaced by the name (slug) of the post which contains the
  contact form.
- `[_post_title]`  This tag will be replaced by the title
  of the post which contains the contact form.
- `[_post_url]`    This tag
  will be replaced by the permalink of the post which contains the
  contact form.
- `[_post_author]` This tag will be replaced by the
  author name of the post which contains the contact form.
- `[_post_author_email]`   This tag will be replaced by the author email
  of the post which contains the contact form.
- `[_serial_number]`   This
  tag will be replaced by a numeric string whose value increments.
  Requires Flamingo 1.5+ be installed.

Hope them will help you, You can also see more here.
[See document for Contact Form 7 Get: post id, post title, post url,..and more](https://contactform7.com/special-mail-tags/)

Comment: The `[_post_***]` tags only work when the form is placed within the post content. If it's part of a sidebar then the fields will be blank.

Answer (score 6):

Install **Contact Form 7 Dynamic Text Extension** and use this code inside form 
**In Form Tab of CF7**

```
[dynamichidden unique-name "CF7_get_post_var key='title'"]
[dynamichidden page-url "CF7_URL"]
```

**In Mail Tab :**

To Output this data , 
you can use the tag [unique-name] in 
Subject or Message body in CF7 Mail tab

For Current Page title : 
[dynamichidden unique-name "CF7_get_post_var key='title'"]

For Current Page Link :
[dynamichidden page-url "CF7_URL"]

Answer (score 0):

Use [ss_post_title] to show your post title in mail content, and write a script in your template file or header/footer.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('.ss_post_title').hide();
   $('.applt').on('click',function()
   {
       var ttlpost = $('.panel-heading.active span.posttitl').text();
       $('.ss_post_title input').val(ttlpost);
   });
});
```

Please use classes according to your code.