# How can I add to Contact Form 7 the reference number of the apartment they're asking for?

Tags: wordpress, plugins, contact-form-7

In my property page there's a green "More Information" button where people add their name, email and telephone. This is made with Contact Form 7. What I need is to add in the email that we receive, the reference number of the property they're asking for and know what property are they interested in. The reference number is down below in the same page, just under the photos and the title. Thanks.

Here's an url example › https://comasrealestate.com/immoble/a-flat-on-the-beach/

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You probably need to add hidden fields and populate it with CF7 mail tags. You can find another answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29374776/how-to-get-post-title-by-contact-form-7 for direction and for a list of CF7 mail tags here https://contactform7.com/special-mail-tags/

Comment: Can you please post the code for the page template that is used for these pages? Do you specifically require the reference number or would the post/page ID or title suffice?

Answer (score 0):

you can simply add this to your form settings

```
Page sent from: [_url]
```

to have the url of the page the form has been submitted.

If you want more you can use the title

```
Page sent from: [_post_title]
```